# python manage.py migrate throwing error using xamp (phpmyadmin) with Django in windows 10

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, migration, manage.py

**Python Version** - 3.7.2
**Django Version** - 2.1.5

I am getting the error below after command `>python manage.py migrate`

please find the attached error message.

```
(py1) C:\Users\tejra\Documents\DjangoProject\Dproject>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 59, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tejra\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Comment: The exception is pretty clear actually. Your MySQL database configuration is not correct. I'd double check `DATABASE` part in `settings.py`.

Comment: yes i changed password in database and it worked.
thank you @GokhanSari.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)